# How to limit outbound SMTP mail sent from PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp, iis-6, fastcgi

We have shared hosting servers which use PHP fastcgi (on IIS) for several clients (shared hosting). Regularly clients use old exploitable code which causes holes in their applications that eventually gets used by hackers to install malicious code. Most of the time this code is being used to send spam from our servers.

We have no control over our clients code, so patching the holes is quite impossible.

We would however like to block the clients sending spam once they send more then X email messages in Y amount of time.

The setup is fastcgi based, so there is little relation between php and the webserver. 
PHP sends its mail through SMTP on localhost. The mailserver allows relay of all localhost connections (obviously).

One thing that goes through my mind is setting an environment variable containing an identifier in the fastcgi environment and using php's prepend file option to add a header to all mail send by php's mailer. After that we could use that mail header to identify the spamming culprit.

The option above still would not take care of spam scripts using regular telnet (telnet localhost, HELO, MAIL FROM etc... ) when sending email.

My question to you: is the idea that i've mentioned the best and perhaps only option to deal with our issue? Or are there better solutions for this situation? And if so, please explain how you would deal with the issue.

Comment: Not sure if this is a programming question you might get a better response on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I was in doubt too. Simply not sure if the solution would be on the PHP's end, the smtp server's end or both.. Well probably both. I do think one would need knowledge of both and I expect more PHP coders to have server knowledge then vice versa. If I fail to get answers here though, ill ask for a move to serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected it seems Stack Overflow is not the right place for this question. The provided answers do not expose some clear method to identify FastCGI sessions' connections to the MTA (SMTP) server.

I will go with my initial concept of adding an identifier to php's environment. This identifier can be read in PHP's **prepend** file by using the [`getenv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) function. This identifier can then be added to mail headers for outgoing mail.

Furthermore I have enabled the [`mail.add_x_header`](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.add-x-header) ini setting which will help identify which script caused the spam run.

I am leaving the question open for the bounty duration, hoping other options will magically appear :)

Comment: Prepend file (and PHP code solution in general) is not really straight forward and easy to manipulate. Better is with the ini values. Configure your FCGI wrapper to set these ini settings based on environment. I know this works well on linux systems and I technically see no reason to not do the same on windows.

Comment: Better yet, ask this question on serverfault.com. This is a sysadmin question.

Comment: That was already suggested. Fact is the solution could aswell require alot of php aswell as server side configuration. I expect more php coders to know sysadmin tasks then sysadmins knowing php. However, the question has already been flagged with a request for moving to serverfault

Answer (score 4):

You can filter that on you MTA (message transfer agent). For example, allow no more than 50 emails in 1 hour for each user in Exim ( http://www.exim.org ) config file (/etc/exim/exim.conf):

```
begin acl

acl_check_not_smtp:
warn ratelimit = 0 / 1h / strict / $sender_address_local_part
log_message = Sender rate $sender_rate / $sender_rate_perio

acl_not_smtp = acl_not_smtp
begin acl
acl_not_smtp:
        deny message = Sender rate overlimit - $sender_rate / $sender_rate_period
        ratelimit = 50 / 1h / strict
        accept
```

And no matter how they try to send, via php mail() or other method.

Comment: Several smtp servers have that setting yes, but it all comes down to knowing the user. When users send through non-authenticated smtp on localhost, there is no obvious way to tell which user is sending the emails. It could still be done by only allowing known email adresses in the "From", but that could still easily be spoofed and it would complicate matters for customers using our servers as webhost while using their own office mail servers (yet still sending mail from their "office" address in the From field)

Comment: Do yo have some software what allow to manage your clients? I mean, do you use CPanel ( http://cpanel.net ) or something like that? CPanel, for example, has settings to do what you need: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/TweakSettings#Mail . If you don't use any system for manage you clients, you can try to do that directly on your firewall.

Comment: But how would this deal with localhost connections that are not authenticated smtp? I can't enforce authenticated SMTP, since this would impact existing users.

Comment: It's a shared hosting, right? So all clients have own domain names but one localhost. You can separate it by domains. For example for CPanel: Login to WHM >> Tweak Settings >> The maximum each domain can send out per hour (0 is unlimited).

Comment: We are not using CPanel, but our own environment. The problem is "each domain" in that example. What determines the "domain", php's `mail()` is sending mail to `localhost:25` without authentication. How would one determine what domain is sending the email? See my first comment.

Comment: So you need some SMTP relay (like http://emailrelay.sourceforge.net ) which will take ALL emails from clients and check it by some rules. Youcan block port 25 for local users and transfer it to port 10025 (example). On this port all emails will be catched by SMTP relay, limits will be checked and if all good - send it to your SMTP server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32256/discussion-between-damien-overeem-and-toxabes)

Comment: +1. This is a good solution, although worded a bit poorly. The idea here is to configure the web servers running PHP to forward mail through some common MTA (if you don't have one, set one up). The MTA then applies filtering logic to all messages, allowing you, the administrator, to block outgoing mail based on whatever parameters you like (such as send rate). The added benefit is that this MTA can be used by other systems as well (other internal web servers, or application servers that allow sending email) to provide a central management/logging hub for all outbound email.

Answer (score 2):

Most shared hosts block the use of PHP's mail() function, as that can be easily exploited. Instead they advice using sendmail or similar scripts which require SMTP authentication before sending. Assuming you're not already doing this, once implemented, you should be able to keep track of number of emails sent from a particular domain/email account and put restrictions on it.

Comment: I do understand your solution. They key in this is authenticated smtp, but considering the fact that we have quite a few users and existing code on our servers, we do not have the option to force those users to adjust their code. (Well we -could-, but that would probably mean a very busy support desk). The solution has to be without impact for our customers.

Answer (score 2):

Okay,  stick with me on this one.  I have not implemented it but it looks good.

The concept here is that you could

1. run a php file before EVERY page on your customers site
2. in that php file rename the mail function to mail_internal().
3. in that php create a new function called mail to do your check / verification that your customer is allowed to send mail,  and if they are call the mail_internal() function with the same parameters.

You will have to install the runkit PECL extension 
http://us.php.net/manual/en/runkit.installation.php

**Changes**

in php.ini

```
auto_prepend_file /var/www/allclients_forcedfile.php
```

in /var/www/allclients_forcedfile.php

```
runkit_function_rename ( "mail" , "mail_internal" );
function mail (   $to ,   $subject ,   $message, $additional_headers = "",   $additional_parameters ="" )
{
     $args = func_get_args();
     error_log("mail_internal : $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] : ".implode(" : ",$args));
     //lookup whether you want to send more mail for this client  maybe by keeping a counter in some file in the $SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]
     if($sendmoremail)
            return mail_internal (   $args[0],   $args[1] ,   $args[2], $args[3]  ,   $args[4]   );
     return false;
}
```

Comment: You know, I actually hadn't thought of that. Although I have yet to test this on our windows environment (not sure if the runkit extension exists for windows, but it is an interesting thought. +1 in any case. I'll try this out.

Comment: I'd love to hear if it works.  Using this I can picture a very cool library that extends many built in functions to give hosts control over them